# The right setup for a database context class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to teach myself asp.net mvc and I am not sure how to do the right setup for the dbcontext class.

First I installed entity framework on my project.
Then I created a model looking like this:

```
 public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Content { get; set; }

        public Post(int PostId, string Title, string Content)
        {
            this.PostId = PostId;
            this.Title = Title;
            this.Content = Content;
        }
```

Afterwards I created a class in the `Models` folder, called `ClassAppContext.cs` and after creating it I did a `enable-migrations`, here is how this class looks :

```
 public class ClassAppContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    }
```

Can someone tell me if my approach was right, and if not, what did I do wrong?

Also, how can I create the database from these classes, I though it is autogenerated, but I don't see a DB in my project.

Comment: [Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Have you already database - do you try to use "code first to exist database"?

Answer (score 1):

So a couple of things. You are on the right track.

You will need to override the OnModelCreating() method in your context class and also define a Initialization strategy along with the Entity Configuration Map (this is ideal to create it in a separate class, but you could have it in the method OnModelCreating as well). So your context class can look something like:

```
public class ClassAppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public ClassAppContext() : base("name=ClassAppDbContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ClassAppContext>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove(new PluralizingTableNameConvention());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof(PostMap).Assembly);
    }
}

public class PostMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Post>
{
    public PostMap()
    {
        ToTable("Post");
        HasKey(x => x.PostId)
            .Property(x => x.PostId)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        Property(x => x.Title)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
            .HasMaxLength(250);

        Property(x => x.Content)
            .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
            .HasMaxLength(500);
    }
}
```

Your **ClassAppDbContext** is your connection string name defined in your web.config (also in app.config if you have context in a separate assembly).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Will this code create the DB, or I'll have to do something extra?:)

Comment: You will have to enable entity framework migrations. So open the Package Manager console and type **enable-migrations -enableautomaticmigrations**. After that type **update-database** and that will create the database for your given that your connection string is correct and the project builds.

Comment: I would also suggest reading up on Entity Framework migrations on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554735(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: To use "code first" in oder to create **new db** you do not need so much code - just add to the answer `public ClassAppContext() : base("name=ClassAppDbContext")` and set **web.config/app.config** e.g.: `<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DBConnection" connectionString="data source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=poststore.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>`

Comment: No. Just setting a connection string and passing it along to your context wont trigger a DB creating unless you have migrations enabled. The rest of the code is not to create the DB but a better approach to manage Code first approach scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I made it to the point where i see the DbConnection in the Server Explorer, but it prompts me for a username and password for SQL Server Authentication, and I don't have such a password or user. I set the integrated securitu to false, which didn't help much. Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion at this point would be to contact your DBA :) You need to have permission to access the DB server and the database and need to have proper user rights to create Databases etc. Using Integrated Security means that you are telling SQL server to use your Windows credentials (prob from AD) to authenticate. But the server needs to authorize this procedure

Comment: Maybe `ClassAppContext` and  _<add name="`DBConnection`"..._ have to be same name. Try `<add name="ClassAppContext"`.

Comment: NO, your context class name and your connection string name are two entirely different things. You pass the name of the connection string into the base class constructor from your context class by setting the name parameter.